# Is there a way to catch typos when writing CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jslint

This small CoffeeScript contains a typo

```
drinks = "Coffee"
drinks = drinks + ", " + "Tea"
drinsk = drinks + ", " + "Lemonade"
alert drinks
```

The intention was to alert "Coffee, Tea, Lemonade" but the result is instead "Coffee, Tea".
The generated JavaScript is still valid and passes JSLint; it declares the variables before usage which
is good, but its the wrong variables.

```
var drinks, drinsk;
drinks = "Coffee";
drinks = drinks + ", " + "Tea";
drinsk = drinks + ", " + "Lemonade";
alert(drinks);
```

If the same example was written in plain JavaScript then JSLint would catch the error:

```
var drinks;
drinks = "Coffee";
drinks = drinks + ", " + "Tea";
drinsk = drinks + ", " + "Lemonade";
alert(drinks);

------------------
Problem at line 4 character 1: 'drinsk' was used before it was defined.
drinsk = drinks + ", " + "Lemonade";
```

**To the question:** Is there a way to keep the errors I make so that I can find them? I would love to see tools like JSLint still work.

Also tried http://www.coffeelint.org/ and it tells me "Your code is lint free!"

Answer (score 4):

You can use IDE which supports identifier spellchecking, for example, IntelliJ IDEA which BTW has a plugin for CoffeScript editing.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the earlier you find these errors the better. Will try the editor as soon as I get on a faster line..

Comment: Just tried IntelliJ and from what I can see it thinks that both "drinks" and "drinsk" are variables (italic font and purple color), also there's a green square in the top left corner (no errors found).

Comment: In IntelliJ there's a spell checker which should add a green wave under an incorrectly spelled word. Something like this: http://blog.novoj.net/binary/2010/11/dictionary-before.png

Answer (score 2):

I'd solve this by writing specs for your JavaScript. Lint type tools are great, but there are still plenty of other mistakes you can make.

Personally I use [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) via jasmine-headless-webkit for this

Comment: while unit tests are important, they're not the whole story.  A lint like tool would be a useful addition to CoffeeScript.

Comment: Yes, will use tests as well, but I think in this case it's the compiler doing wrong. It's clear that `drinsk` is only assigned to and never read so it makes no sense to make it a variable.

Comment: I won't argue that stuff like warnings for unused variables aren't a good thing!