# How to catch typos errors in VIM for EmberJS (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, vim, ember.js

I am starting to learn EmberJS/JS/VIM . I was going through the official ToDoMVC guide for EmberJS, and I ran into typos errors that was really really hard to detect with the "eyes" and the browser really didn't help in this case at all. So, can you please suggest me what tools or techniques that can be used to detect these types of typos errors?

For example:

```
### todo_controller should've been todos_controller
<script src="js/todo_controller.js"></script>

### catching the end of { } closed scoping

### typo within a model js "property"
inflection: function() {
  var remaining = this.get('remaining');
  return remaining === 1 ? 'todo' : 'todos';
}.proprety('remaining')
```

EDIT;

Yes, I did search before posting here. The first was this website, and the comments here basically suggest DreamWeaver [Frustration with Typos](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/typos_javascript).

I searched SO itself (through google), and there was [Is there a way to catch typos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835697/is-there-a-way-to-catch-typos-when-writing-coffeescript). I did find out there is something called LINT, but it dealt with coffeescript.

I did find out [ember.vim](https://github.com/dsawardekar/ember.vim) as you pointed out before, but as you see the README in the github profile, i believe it strictly wants you to follow the layout as prescribed. It may be a good thing in future, but right now, I wanted to just stick with what the official ToDoMVC way. I am just beginning to get a hang of hjkl, so I do not think I can makes changes to it to fit my way. Also, second point, is the layout format it supports is [Ember-AppKit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit) which has been deprecated. SO I am having doubts if I should follow the layout pattern itself.

And all of them didn't particularly address what I am asking. In the todo_controller typo above, the browser didn't throw any sort of errors. I am using FF/Firebug, and on the Console, it only showed the message about Ember loading, and no errors at all. It took me a while to see that typo. The second one did throw errors, but typos are a hard thing to discover in VIM. The third one, took a bit of time, and there were others. These don't throw errors at all. I am used to PHP, and while there is no direct showing of errors as in Android, I am finding Javascript typo hunting to be very hard.

Answer (score 1):

it took me like 3 looks before I saw your typo.

Set your browser to pause on exceptions (sometimes pause on Caught Exceptions).  It's been one of the quickest ways I've found to track down a weird bug.  In this case I'm sure you were getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function...`.

Comment: I have updated my question. I actually was not getting that error. I am using FF/Firebug, though I don't know if pause on exceptions was on.

Comment: Also, I believe, that catching other people's typos is a lot sooner than your owns. Tricks of the mind!

Comment: lol, I wasn't trying to say it was easy to find at all!  I was saying it was a super tough typo.  Even though you essentially told me where it was, and only included 3 lines and said there was a typo, and it took a long time for me to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take this the wrong way, but did you try to search before asking? There has been, for quite a while now, a plugin for Vim that has syntax highlighting improvements.

https://github.com/dsawardekar/ember.vim

Beyond that plugin, you could try writing your own solution. I haven't tried, but I doubt there is anything out there that will pick up spelling errors for Ember...

I use JSLint for SublimeText 3, which lints as you code so you get a live update of any potential bugs. Kinda nice. Here's something similar for Vim: https://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim

As @kingpin2k suggests, you should really learn how to use your browser tools. The big three are just jam-packed full with development and debug tools. 9 times out of 10 it gives you the line and column of the error, and you can set breakpoints within the code to watch it execute in-context. And, that is really just the tip of the iceberg in terms of how detailed you can get with debugging in-browser.

Comment: I have updated the answer, in regards to ember.vim. Do you still recommend that to me. I kinda of don't want to stick with boilerplates, but I don't think I am sufficiently good to write my own solution yet. LINT seems like the solution, but I still don't know what exactly that does. Hasn't the JS ecosystem reached a near level of compiled typo catching environment? This would not have been a time consuming endeavor in Eclipse/Android.